# Split string using another string as seperator (e.g. split :1 from 123:1)

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

i create an string array pass by javascript with the value 
"621:1,622:1,623:1,624:1,"

i have no clue for how to delimeter ":1" or :2 from the string array with different function

```
 char[] delimiterChars = { '1' };
 char[] delimiterChars = { ':' };

 string[] words = text.Split(delimiterChars);
 string text = "621:1,622:1,623:1,624:1,";

 string[] words = text.Split(delimiterChars);
 System.Console.WriteLine("{0} words in text:", words.Length);

        string save  = "";
        foreach (string s in words)
        {                 
             System.Console.WriteLine(s);
        }
```

Comment: *i have no clue for how to delimeter* ... you mean how to *extract* values `1, 2` out of the string?

Comment: What did you expect to have in `words`? What about `char[] delimiterChars = { ':', ',' };`.

Comment: Are you trying to get the 621 part or the 1 part?

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos yes, Georg Patschieder post the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [String.Split(String[], StringSplitOptions)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf(v=vs.110).aspx) overload:

```
string[] delimiterStrings = new []{ ":1," };
string text = "621:1,622:1,623:1,624:1,";
string[] words = text.Split(delimiterStrings, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

[.net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/6gcv3z)

Result:

4 words in text:
621
622
623
624

Comment: thank you very much for the good solution @Georg Patscheider

Comment: Glad I could help you :)